# How to cancel existing appointment from yahoo calendar via ics file?

Tags: icalendar

I want to create ics file which will cancel existing events from calendar. I looked on the internet and got the solution for it too.I used METHOD:CANCEL and STATUS:CANCELLED in that ics file and by doing this way i am able to cancel events from google calendar but it is not canceling appointments from yahoo calendar and Outlook 2013. So can anyone please help me regarding this issue?Here is my ics file-`BEGIN:VCALENDAR

```
PRODID:-//Sample//Sample Calendar//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Calcutta
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160129T040000
DTEND:20160129T050000
DESCRIPTION:Your appointment Details:
LOCATION: Chennai
SEQUENCE:0
PRIORITY:5
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:Appointment Details:- Kou Kul
UID:X:201600U28000009M052EAC@sample
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `UID` of the cancel event the same as the event's original `UID`?  Also, you may need to increment the `SEQUENCE` property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael.Yes UID is the same as of the original UID. And I have read that For cancelation of Events you dont need to update sequence no.Please Help me with this problem.